# c++ how to call pure virtual method from multiple derived classes from one function?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to call a pure virtual function from a loop?

Some pseudocode to explain what im trying to achive

(tried a version of the following example but got error: object of abstract class type "Base" is not allowed)

```
class Base{
  public:
    virtual void printMe() =0;
};

class derivedOne{
  public:
    void printMe(){std::cout << "one "<<endl;
};

class derivedTwo{
  public:
    void printMe(){std::cout << "two"<<endl;
};

class holder{
  private:
   vector<derivedOne> one;
   vector<derivedTwo> two;
   void printDerive(vector<Base> bases){
      for (Base base: bases)
      {
        base.printMe();
      }
   };
};
```

All derived classes implement the function printMe (because its a pure virtual function in base).
Im trying to avoid writing a print loop for each class that implemented printMe from base because the functions will all do the same (loop the items in a vector and call printMe).

Comment: You can't create a vector of objects of abstract type but you can create a vector of pointers (either smart or not) or references for such objects. This approach solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a `vector<Base>` or have `Base base` in your range-based for loop, because `Base` is abstract and both of those require constructing a `Base`.

One solution would be to store `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` for both `one` and `two` so that you can get dynamic dispatch:

```
class holder{
private:
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> one;
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> two;
public:
   void printDerive(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>& bases){
      for (auto&& base: bases)
      {
        base->printMe();
      }
   };
};
```

Another option would be to keep your storage as-is and have a template function to print them:

```
class holder{
private:
   std::vector<derivedOne> one;
   std::vector<derivedTwo> two;
public:
   template <class T>
   void printDerive(const std::vector<T>& ts){
      for (auto&& t: ts)
      {
        t.printMe();
      }
   };
};
```

These solutions will have consequences for how you allocate the elements and use the vectors, so choose based on your other requirements.

Comment: Thanks, the compiler did not give an error on function void printDerive(vector<Base> bases) without any contents in the brackets so i thought it would be allowd.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be creating the `vector<Base>`: this is not allowed, as it requires instantiation of an abstract class, `Base`.

You could have a `vector` of *pointers* to base, as it is only pointers (and references) that can behave polymorphically (note: your function should take the `vector` by `const` reference rather than by value):

```
void printDerive(const vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>& bases){
      for (auto& base: bases)
      {
        base->printMe();
      }
};
```